# sum only the negative values in a row from an xts-object

Tags: r, matrix, sum, xts, zoo

I have an xts-object and **I want to sum only the negative values** in the first row.

The code

```
sum(test[test<0])
```

gives me the error

```
Error in `[.xts`(test, test < 0) : 'i' or 'j' out of range
```

but

```
sum(test[1],na.rm=TRUE)
```

works, but then I have the sum of all the values, not just the negative ones:

[1] -0.9786889

Without giving an example of data yet, does anybody know why this simple code doesnt work?

The dimension of the xts-object is `> dim(test)` is  `216  39`.

Comment: _"Without giving an example of data yet"_: Why not?

Comment: negsum(test[,1]) calculates the column values...

Comment: @Axe I dont really know how, isnt it very complicated?

Comment: @jogo This gives me `Error in `[.xts`(x, x < 0) : 'i' or 'j' out of range`

Comment: @jackbauer Please give a [mcve]!

Comment: This might be related to this open xts issue --> https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/198 I'm not sure it is related, but it looks like this has been an ongoing issue for the last two years, and is still open. They note that "Subset selection for the full zoo/xts object is always done "along" the time index, so subsetting with a logical vector or matrix does not work."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chance that this is related to the open xts issue here ---> [here](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/198)

It appears that xts objects cannot be subset in this manner. Instead, you should use `coredata()`, an xts function that treats the "core data" as a matrix.

It's a little messy but:

```
sum(coredata(test)[1,][coredata(test)[1,] < 0]
```

should work. If you wanted to do this for all rows, you would need to use something like apply() or a for loop.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be a bug. It worked with `coredata()` !! Thank you @Jared Marks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possibilities:

```
sum(pmin(test[1], 0), na.rm = TRUE)

sum(test[1] * (test[1] < 0), na.rm = TRUE)

sum(Filter(function(x) x < 0, coredata(test[1])))
```