# Divide negative/positive values in row by another row in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, apply, xts

### **Data copied with dput**

(My first data sample example, I hope this is enough)

I have this xts-object `weights`

```
> dput(head(weights,4))
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, 
-0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, 
-0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0, 0, 0, 0, -0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.333333333333333), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(946512000, 949276800, 951782400, 
954460800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(4L, 39L
), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("ABB.N", "ACTELION.N", "ADECCO.N", 
"ALUSUISSE.N", "BALOISE.N", "CIBA.SC.N", "CLARIANT.N", "CS.GROUP.N", 
"ELEKTROWATT.I", "EMS.CHEMIE", "GEBERIT.N", "GIVAUDAN.N", "JULIUS.BAER.N", 
"KUDELSKI.I", "LAFARGEHOLCIM.N", "LONZA.N", "NESTLE.N", "NOBEL.BIOCARE.N", 
"NOVARTIS.I", "NOVARTIS.N", "RICHEMONT.N", "ROCHE.GS", "SAIRGROUP.N", 
"SBV.N", "SERONO..B..I", "SGS.N", "SULZER.N", "SWATCH.I", "SWATCH.N", 
"SWISS.LIFE.HOLDING.AG.N", "SWISS.RE.N", "SWISSCOM.N", "SYNGENTA.N", 
"SYNTHES.N", "TRANSOCEAN.N", "UBS.GROUP.N", "UBS.I", "UNAXIS.N20", 
"ZURICH.INSURANCE.N")))
```

and two numeric vectors `Pos` and `Neg`

```
> dput(head(Pos,4))
c(`1999-12-30` = 0.34191022613305, `2000-01-31` = 0.411653443805752, 
`2000-02-29` = 0.393078629707615, `2000-03-31` = 0.376686025847744
)

> dput(head(Neg,4))
c(`1999-12-30` = -1.32059915686837, `2000-01-31` = -1.27821843244263, 
`2000-02-29` = -1.3142472840903, `2000-03-31` = -1.32647296498383)
```

### **What I want to do**

I now want to divide each negative/positive value in `weights` by the corresponding row in `Neg` or `Pos` (if `Neg` and `Pos` were to be transformed to a matrix/dataframe)

### **Problems**

I tried for-loops, apply-functions and simple division with conditions but I never got the desired result which cant be so difficult  for such a rather simple task...

[From the last problem I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155822/sum-only-the-negative-values-in-a-row-from-an-xts-object) there seems to be also problems with subsetting from xts-objects...

**These codes didnt work for me: (mostly errors with dimensions or subscripts...)**

For loop:

```
weights_adj <- apply(weights,1,function(x) if (coredata(x)[coredata(x)>0]){
  coredata(x)[coredata(x)]/Pos
} else if (coredata(x)[coredata(x)<0]){
  coredata(x)[coredata(x)]/Neg
})
```

apply function:

```
weights_adj <- apply(weights,1,function(x) (coredata(x)[coredata(x)>0])/Pos)
```

which + apply:

```
which_negative_weight <- t(apply(weights,1,function (x) which(x<0)))

result_negative <- apply(weights,1,function(x) x[,which_negative_weight[1,]])
```

which + for:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(weights)){
  (weights[i,which_negative_weight[i,]]/Neg[i,])
}
```

### **EDIT:**

**The solution from @K.Hua worked and he helped me very quickly, but @G.Grothendieck's solution is simpler and faster!**

Comment: If one value in a row is negative, is the whole row negative?

Comment: no why should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to divide a sample of a vector of size N by a whole vector of size N. Besides, I think it's easier to do a loop over the columns instead :

```
weights_adj = weights
neg <- apply(weights,2,function (x) x<0)
for (i in 1:ncol(weights)){
  weights_adj[neg[,i],i] = weights[neg[,i],i]/Neg[neg[,i]]
  weights_adj[!neg[,i],i] = weights[!neg[,i],i]]/Pos[!neg[,i]]
}
```

Comment: Wow it actually worked. Could you explain further what was exactly wrong in my approach? I am not grasping it yet...

Comment: I never knew that one could simply take a logical vector as a column subset argument???

Comment: As I said, you tried to divide by the whole vectors 'Neg' or 'Pos' but you were sampling the row you were dividing, hence the dimension error. Plus, usually it's better to work with columns in R than in rows as you are usually sure that you are dealing with the same variable class

Comment: Okay thanks for the further explanation, will definitely try to remember this!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
weights / ((weights > 0) * Pos + (weights < 0) * Neg + (weights == 0))
```